# Определить общие темы среди множеств слов

Tags: python, текст

Путем долгих переборов, удалений, парсинга, стемминга и др. анализов я пришел к ТОП 10 слов для каждой лекции с ted.com. Они достаточно уникальные, т.е. среди 2346 множеств слов максимально из них повторяется не более 50 слов.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы выявить на основе полученных 2346 множеств слов по 10 схожие. Простое пересечение множеств каждого с каждым ни к чему не приводит (длина пересечения 1-3). Нужно использовать синонимы. Пытался разобраться с gensim и nltk, но ни к чему не пришел. LSA не настроил.

Направьте на истинный путь в этом нелегком деле.

Comment: м.б. определить  Cosine distance  для top слов с использованием Word2Vec?

Comment: Сложно будет показать какие конкретно слова нашлись?

Comment: А точно среди найденных слов нет разных форм одного и того же? Если так, то можно использовать, например, [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), чтобы их выявить. Ну и воспользоваться базой синонимов - хорошая идея(возможно, подойдёт что-то с http://en.softonic.com/s/english-synonym-dictionary ). Далее количество множеств должно снизиться в несколько раз.

Comment: Я бы использовал word2vec. Попытался бы найти какую-нибудь базу с синонимами. И, разумеется, лемматизация, если вы её ещё не сделали

Answer (score 2):

Если без использования всяких word2vec и подобных, можно попробовать разработать алгоритм такого типа:

1. Для каждого исходного слова из ваших 2346 множеств составить таблицу частоты встречаемости прочих слов взятых из тех же предложений, в которых встречается ваше слово, можно даже не все слова брать, а ближайшие слова находящиеся перед и после исходного слова.
2. Для каждого найденного слова найти таким же способом рядом стоящие слова (т.е. контекст), и сгруппировать эти слова в единый список отсортированный по частоте встречаемости и отфильтрованный так, чтобы в списке оставались только те слова, которые присутствуют в Ваших 2346 множествах слов.
3. Полученный из этого списка топ10 будет состоять из слов, которыми можно заменить исходное слово.
4. PROFIT

Предварительно, конечно же, нужно всё это обработать всяким там стеммингом и др. анализом.

А по поводу простого пересечения множеств, возникла такая идея: попробовать пересекать не по словам, а по выделенным корням слов, т.е. чтобы пересекались однокоренные слова.

Ну и напоследок полезная ссылка: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0